# .htaccess redirects for www and non www for entire site and specific pages seem to be failing

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Trying to redirect all traffic from www.old-domain.co.uk and old-domain.co.uk to www.new-domain.co.uk on a Wordpress install but also need to redirect some specific pages to new URLS. I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

redirect 301 /xxx/4533644418 http://www.new-domain.com/xxx/
redirect 301 /yyy/4533644413 http://www.new-domain.com/yyy/
redirect 301 /zzz/4533681089 http://www.new-domain.com/zzz/
```

This seems to work but the problem is that if I enter a trash url - e.g. old-domain.co.uk/trash.html - it 404s but the address bar still shows the old-domain (old-domain.co.uk/trash.html) instead of redirecting as I expect (www.new-domain.com/trash.html).

I'm worried this may indicate an error in my redirect approach and would appreciate any advice. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trash URL is matched by the Wordpress section and never reaches your Rule to redirect to the new site. Move the redirect rule to the top as below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Most specific Rules should be at the top
redirect 301 /xxx/4533644418 http://www.new-domain.com/xxx/
redirect 301 /yyy/4533644413 http://www.new-domain.com/yyy/
redirect 301 /zzz/4533681089 http://www.new-domain.com/zzz/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please also read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7714/when-someone-answers-my-question-correctly-and-completely-what-should-i-do :-)